# A tangent to an ellipse makes angles $\alpha$ with major axis and $\beta$ with a focal radius; show that the eccentricity is $\cos\beta/\cos\alpha$.

Tags: conic-sections

> If the tangent at any point of the ellipse make an angle $\alpha$ with the major axis and an angle $\beta$ with the focal radius of the point of contact, then show that the eccentricity of the ellipse is given by $$e=\dfrac{\cos\beta}{\cos\alpha}$$

How is this derived? Please explain with a proper diagram.

Answer (score 2):

Let $F$ and $G$ be the foci of the ellipse.
The bisector $PB$ of $\angle FPG$ is perpendicular to tangent $PQ$. Hence:
$$
\begin{align}
e&={FB+GB\over FP+GP}\quad\text{(definition)}\\
&={FB\over FP}\quad\text{(angle bisector theorem)}\\
&={\sin(\pi/2-\beta)\over\sin(\pi/2-\alpha)}\quad\text{(sine rule)}\\
&={\cos\beta\over\cos\alpha}.
\end{align}
$$

[image]